# Can an old fashioned crypt encrypted file be brute forced, if so how?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, brute-force

If I encrypt a file using the old Unix/Linux `crypt()` function, how can it be decrypted or attacked?

I understand how a password file (for example) is attacked, you guess passwords, run them through `crypt()` and see if the result matches the entry in `/etc/passwd` (well, `/etc/shadow` on modern systems).

However, I don't see how you can do this with an encrypted file, you can't seriously guess the contents of the file and run that through the `crypt()` function to see if you get a match for the encrypted file.

Comment: Did you meant the old `crypt` utility? The `crypt` function isn't useful to encrypt data.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of cracking an encrypted file is trying different keys until you get a result which *makes sense*. How do you know you found such a result?  Usually because you know the resulting file must have some kind of internal structure. For example, when you know the decrypted file is in an XML format, you would run every result through an XML validator. Or when you know the decrypted file has its own checksum somewhere, you would check if it matches. When you expect natural language text, you could check the letter frequency to be similar to natural language.  On UNIX systems you have the tool `file` which can detect many common file formats. When it returns something, it might be a possible hit.

But when you have no idea at all what might be the content of the file, you have no way to tell if the garbage returned by applying the algorithm with a random key is in fact the garbage you are looking for.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's much as I thought.  It means that, although the Unix crypt() function isn't very secure it would still be very difficult to crack my files because they contain fairly random data.  It is human readable of course but it's not by any means text or structured in any particular way.

Comment: @ChrisGreen That depends on how random they are. When they are human readable, they might be vulnerable to a known plaintext attack (when the attacker knows that a specific string must occur somewhere in the file, they can exploit this to crack it much faster).